# Salesforce SOQL with datetime literals to pull records between 2 datetime custom fields?

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql, salesforce-communities

I have a requirement where i need to pull all the records between 2 datetime custom fields;.

For example:

custo_Field_1__c  = Oct 10th 12:00pm  (DateTime Field)
custo_Field_2__c  = Oct 15th 10:00pm  (DateTime Field)

Now i need to pull all the records between those custom dates, with date LITERALS ( No apex coding ) ....

SELECT Id 
from Object__c 
where id = '000000000000' AND
custo_Field_1__c <= TODAY  AND  custo_Field_2__c >= TODAY

From the above query i am able to retrieve the records between that two dates  but it they are not specific to time, even on Oct 10th 10am I m able to see those records where as i need to see those records between oct 10th **12:00pm** - 15th oct **10:00 PM**

PLease help me out to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

date LITERALS

```
2018-02-31
```

datetime LITERALS

```
2018-02-31T16:00:00Z
2018-02-31T15:00:00-01:00
```

others

```
LAST_90_DAYS
LAST_FISCAL_QUARTER
LAST_FISCAL_YEAR
LAST_MONTH
LAST_N_DAYS:n
LAST_N_FISCAL_QUARTERS:n
LAST_N_FISCAL_YEARS:n
LAST_N_MONTHS:n
LAST_N_QUARTERS:n
LAST_N_WEEKS:n
LAST_N_YEARS:n
LAST_QUARTER
LAST_WEEK
LAST_YEAR
NEXT_90_DAYS
NEXT_FISCAL_QUARTER
NEXT_FISCAL_YEAR
NEXT_MONTH
NEXT_N_DAYS:n
NEXT_N_FISCAL_QUARTERS:n
NEXT_N_FISCAL_YEARS:n
NEXT_N_MONTHS:n
NEXT_N_QUARTERS:n
NEXT_N_WEEKS:n
NEXT_N_YEARS:n
NEXT_QUARTER
NEXT_WEEK
NEXT_YEAR
THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER
THIS_FISCAL_YEAR
THIS_MONTH
THIS_QUARTER
THIS_WEEK
THIS_YEAR
TODAY
TOMORROW
YESTERDAY
```